# Given directed connected weighted graph, check if d(v) = delta(s,v)

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

I'm having some hard time with this problem. 
Can someone give me some clue/guidance?

This is an homework question, so please don't just solve it.

> Given a weighted directed connected graph $G = (V,E)$  and given another
>   function $d: V \to \mathbb{R}^+$ (including zero), find a linear time algorithm that checks if $d(v)=\text{delta}(s,v)$ for each $v$, for some fixed vertex $s$.
>
> $\text{delta}(s,v)$ is like in Dijkstra algorithm, meaning shortest path from $s$
>   to $v$.

My thought is to make use of BST to check if these functions are equal, but I can't avoid running Dijkstra for it.

Comment: Given a vertex $v$ and all its neighbours $u_1, \dots, u_k$, and assuming that in fact $d(v) = delta(s, v)$, what can you say about $d(v)$ and (some of) the values $d(u_1), \dots, d(u_k)$?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't figure it out. assuming ()=(,) for all v, it means () is greater than each "incoming" vertex (). is that you intent?

Comment: We don't know (or at least don't assume that we know) which vertices are incoming.  But we still know that for at least one neighbour $u_i$ of $v$, either ____ or ____.

Comment: (I'm not yet sure that this is "the right" way to go about this, but it seems likely that the property I have in mind will turn out to be useful.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated a lot!. But still - is it a property of greater/less than? either d(u) > delta(s,u(i)) or equals? and then sort them somehow? I'm stuck with the idea of running Dijkstra :(

Comment: Suppose $v$ has exactly two neighbours, $u_1$ and $u_2$, with edge weights $w(vu_1)=3$ and $w(vu_2)=7$.  Suppose $d(v)=1009$, $d(u_1)=1005$, $d(u_2)=1010$.  Could these $d(\cdot)$ values all be valid?

Comment: Nope.. suppose ()=1009, so the other two d(*) values can't be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d$ indeed represents the length of the shortest path, we must have

$$
d(v)=
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $v=s$,}\\
\displaystyle\min_{u:(u,v)\in E}\{d(u)+w(u,v)\}, &\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
$$

where $w(u,v)$ is the weight of the edge $(u,v)$.

So you can check whether $d$ satisfies this property for all $v$. It takes only linear time. If $d$ does not satisfy this property, it cannot represent the length of the shortest path. However, if $d$ does satisfy this property, does it really represent the length of the shortest path? I'll let you figure out this part.

For a further hint:

> Note what you need to prove is that, for all $v$, $d(v)$ is length of the shortest path from $s$ to $v$. Suppose the shortest path from $s$ to $v$ contains $k$ edges, you may try a mathematical induction on $k$.